# Encrypting and decrypting strings in Python, to match old VB.NET code

Tags: python, vb.net, encryption, des

For quite a few years I've been running a VB.Net application, which used functions for encrypting and decrypting strings. These functions are gratefully taken from a WordPress blog which is now no longer available.

The problem now is that I am making a new Python-based version of the application, but we have databases full of strings that have been encrypted using the old VB.NET version, that I will need to be able to decrypt. So I need Python functions that will decrypt and encrypt to give *exactly* the same results!

In the old code, sending `strText = "Secret message."` and `strEncrKey = "Terribly"` to `encryptString()` would result in this encrypted, database-friendly string: `dqCMClFoMs3B9AjoFGs+cQ==`

(This process could then be reversed with `decryptString()`)

I'm still new to Python and a complete novice on anything to do with encryption or byte conversion, so I don't know how to replicate the equivalent of the 'createEncryptor' function from the VB.NET code.

Here's my Python code as it stands. It uses pyDes (`import pydes`) at the top of the code:

```
    defaultKey = "Terribly"
    charset = "utf-8"
    data = pyDes.des(defaultKey)
    print("pyDes initialised.")
    text_to_encode = "Secret message."
    encrypted = data.encrypt(text_to_encode.encode(charset))
    print("encrypted:", repr(encrypted))
    decrypted = data.decrypt(encrypted).decode(charset)
    print("decrypted:", repr(decrypted))
```

but this code fails to run.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Why is my Python installation bombing out with an `exit code -1073740791` error on the `data.encrypt` line? Am I messing up the syntax?
2. Is it possible to completely replicate the previous encryption and decryption, with matching results each time, and if so, how do I do it?

The old VB.NET code, unchanged for a long time, is as follows:

```vb
Public Function stringEncrypt(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strEncrKey As String) As String
        ' from http://ntcnet.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/encryptdecrypt-string-vbnet/
        If strText.Length = 0 Then Return ""
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
        Try
            Dim bykey() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(strEncrKey, 8))
            Dim InputByteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText)
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(bykey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cs.Write(InputByteArray, 0, InputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function stringDecrypt(ByVal strText As String, ByVal sDecrKey As String) As String
        ' from http://ntcnet.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/encryptdecrypt-string-vbnet/
        If strText.Length = 0 Then Return ""
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
        Dim inputByteArray(strText.Length) As Byte
        Try
            Dim byKey() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(sDecrKey, 8))
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
            inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(strText)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Regarding question 1.: instead of `data.encrypt(text_to_encode.encode(charset))` it should be `data.encrypt(text_to_encode ).encode(charset)`

Comment: Honestly, even though you are clear that you want the Python to work "exactly" the same way, why not instead use the VB.Net code to first decrypt the database strings, then find a more [python-ish](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/crypto/) solution to re-encrypt and decrypt going forward.  Otherwise you're just going to run into the same issue in the future... having to reproduce the exact encryption again in the next fad programming environment, but may find it not immediately possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree @CPerkins that that would be a sensible move. However it is hamstrung by a corporate requirement for the VB.Net version of the app and the Python version to be cross-compatible during a transition period. But yes I will think again about whether it's possible to not be tied into a strict encryption match,

Comment: I wouldn't use this code, it has many flaws - 3DES, static iv, passphrase as key, potential padding oracle, no authentication. Instead I would use an AEAD cipher, with secure pseudorandom key and iv. Now, I think `DESCryptoServiceProvider`'s default mode is CBC with PKCS7 padding, so it may be possible to 'translate' this code to Python with those parameters.